# How do I add a plugin to an Oomph Product setup?

Tags: eclipse, oomph

I would like to create a custom Eclipse that has [Mybatipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/mybatipse) along with some other plugins installed by default. I am using the Oomph Product setup within Eclipse to create my product. My guess is to add a requirement in the P2 director node, but I don't know how to set it up correctly. I have seen examples that put the name of the plugin in the Name section of a Requirement like this `org.eclipse.emf.compare.source.feature.group` but I don't know where to get that info from for the plugins I want. Am I even heading in the right direction?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From their homepage, the P2 Update Site for this plugin is:

```
http://dl.bintray.com/harawata/eclipse
```

## Step 1:

In the the "Repository Explorer (Oomph)" view (you may need to add this view in your Workbench), you can see the plugin:

[image: Repository Explorer (Oomph)]

- Paste the Update site in the first field.
- Select "MyBatipse" item
- You will see the available version.

## Step 2:

In the Setup editor of your product setup file, Create a new "P2 Director" Task:

[image: Create a "P2 Director" child node]

And again create a "Repository" Child in the new created node.

## Step 3:

Double click on the "Repository" node in order to see the properties (a new view should appear. Sometimes you need to do this operation twice bevor you see the properties).

In URL enter the P2 Update site.

[image: Enter the URL properties]

## Step 4:

Back to your Repository explorer view, drag and drop "MyBatipse" on your "P2 Director" node, it will appear as child node.

[image: Oomph drag and drop]

*Note: If you want fixed a precise version of the plugin, you can also drag and drop one of the version from the Repository explorer*

## Result:

If you open your `*.setup` File with a text editor, you should se a section like this:

```
  <setupTask
      xsi:type="setup.p2:P2Task">
    <requirement
        name="net.harawata.mybatipse.feature.feature.group"/>
    <repository
        url="http://dl.bintray.com/harawata/eclipse"/>
  </setupTask>
```